# Include manually-added lines to ggplot2 guide legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

This is question that's been asked many times, I know, but I still can't figure out a good answer. I would like to get a pretty legend that shows manually-added lines in a separate legend on the plot. Here's what I've figured out so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg, color=factor(am))) +
   theme_bw() + 
   geom_point() + 
   geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se=FALSE) + 
   geom_abline(aes(intercept=40, slope = (-1/10))) +
   geom_abline(aes(intercept=25, slope = (-1/30)))
```

gives:

[image]

which has manually-added lines, but no legend entry for them.

## Attempt 1

Just adding `show.legend=TRUE` isn't very helpful:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg, color=factor(am))) +
    theme_bw() + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se=FALSE) + 
    geom_abline(aes(intercept=40, slope = (-1/10)), show.legend = TRUE) +
    geom_abline(aes(intercept=25, slope = (-1/30)), show.legend = TRUE)
```

[image]

## Attempt 2

Adding an artificial `fill` for each additional line isn't very helpful, either:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg, color=factor(am))) +
   theme_bw() + 
   geom_point() + 
   geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se=FALSE) + 
   geom_abline(aes(intercept=40, slope = (-1/10), fill='Comparison Line 1')) +
   geom_abline(aes(intercept=25, slope = (-1/30), fill='Comparison Line 2'))
```

it just gives a warning and returns the original plot:

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
```

[image]

## Attempt 3

Adding both `show.legend=TRUE` and a fake aes `fill` gets close, but the result is very ugly:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg, color=factor(am))) +
   theme_bw() + 
   geom_point() + 
   geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se=FALSE) + 
   geom_abline(aes(intercept=40, slope = (-1/10), fill='Comparison Line 1'), show.legend = TRUE) +
   geom_abline(aes(intercept=25, slope = (-1/30), fill='Comparison Line 2'), show.legend = TRUE)
```

[image]

Finally, my question:
How do I get rid of the diagonal lines in the color legend (titled "factor(am)"), and how do I get normal-looking lines next to the items in the fill legend (titled "fill")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close!
Add dummy variable that is relevant to `geom_abline` for example `size` to `aes()`. And scale `size` back using `scale_size_manual`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg, color=factor(am))) +
   theme_bw() + 
   geom_point() + 
   geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se=FALSE) + 
   geom_abline(aes(intercept=40, slope = (-1/10), size='Comparison Line 1')) +
   geom_abline(aes(intercept=25, slope = (-1/30), size='Comparison Line 2')) +
   scale_size_manual(values = c(0.3, 0.3))
```

[image]

PS.: Fill that you were using is unknown aesthetics for the abline (as `ggplot2` warns you: `Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill`).

Comment: This looks great as long as the 2 lines look the same, but when the 2 lines are different size, type, or color, the legend doesn't reflect those differences:    

    `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg, color=factor(am))) +  
       theme_bw() +  
       geom_point() +  
       geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se=FALSE) +  
       geom_abline(aes(intercept=40, slope = (-1/10), size='Comparison 
Line 1'), alpha = .5) +  
       geom_abline(aes(intercept=25, slope = (-1/30), size='Comparison Line 2'),color='red', linetype=2) +  
       scale_size_manual(values = c(1, 0.3))`

Comment: And, to answer my own question, I need to add in `guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype=c(1,2), color=c('black', 'red')))` to the scale_xxx_manual() function: `scale_size_manual(values = c(1, 0.3), guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype=c(1,2), color=c('black', 'red'))))`